# Visual Basic Teacher example does not work correctly

Tags: vb.net

just had a walkthrough in class and the example code our teacher gave us does not return a value. I am having alot of trouble with my current assignment because I do not see whats wrong with it. It is supposed to take two numbers entered by the user and add them together for a total with a tax rate, but it continues to return all 0's
heres what the code looks like:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub BtnCalc_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _ 
 ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnCalc.Click

    Dim amount1 As Decimal
    Dim amount2 As Decimal
    Dim myinvoice As Invoice

    myinvoice = New Invoice

    myinvoice.setlineitemamount(amount1 = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBoxAmt1.Text))
    myinvoice.setlineitemamount2(amount2 = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBoxAmt2.Text))

    LblTotal.Text = myinvoice.calculateinvoicetotal

    MessageBox.Show(myinvoice.getlineitemamount2)

    amount1 = TextBoxAmt1.Text
    amount2 = TextBoxAmt2.Text

End Sub

End Class
```

And heres the code inside my class:

```
Public Class Invoice
'created new class for my invoice functions

Private lineItemamount1 As Decimal
Private lineItemamount2 As Decimal
Private lineItemamount3 As Decimal
Private lineItemamount4 As Decimal
Private invoiceDate As Date
Private customer As Integer
Private invoicetotal As Decimal
Private invoicetaxrate As Decimal = 0.1

Public Function getlineitemamount()
    Return lineItemamount1
End Function

Public Sub setlineitemamount(ByVal amount1 As Decimal)
    lineItemamount1 = amount1
End Sub

Public Function getlineitemamount2()
    Return lineItemamount2
End Function

Public Sub setlineitemamount2(ByVal amount2 As Decimal)
    lineItemamount2 = amount2
End Sub

Public Function calculateinvoicetotal()
    Return (lineItemamount1 + lineItemamount2) * invoicetaxrate
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Does TextBoxAmt1.Text worth something when you debug

Comment: im using the express version i dont think debugging shows values throughout, but i use messageboxes to show what their values are, and no matter what i enter into the textbox their values ALWAYS remain zero

Comment: if you do a messagebox.show(TextBoxAmt1.Text) whats the value

Comment: when i do the messagebox.show(textboxAmt1.text) instead of MessageBox.Show(myinvoice.getlineitemamount) it DOES return a value for what i entered--- is there a better way to refer to your class for the textbox to return the value you enter in the txbx?

Comment: good, I just wanted to make sure that your input was good. 1 sec, im gonna find what's the problem.

Comment: Go into your project properties and turn on Option Strict and then fix any errors that are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this plz

```
amount1 = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBoxAmt1.Text)
myinvoice.setlineitemamount(amont1)
```

And

```
Public Function getlineitemamount2() as decimal
```

when it's a function you need to specify the TYPE of the returned value
but i'm not sure it's your problem but it worths a try

Comment: "Option Strict On requires all Function, Property, and Operator declarations to have an 'As' clause" - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44h6ck64%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

These lines are probably the problem:

```
myinvoice.setlineitemamount(amount1 = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBoxAmt1.Text))
myinvoice.setlineitemamount2(amount2 = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBoxAmt2.Text))
```

Rewrite them as:

```
myinvoice.setlineitemamount(Convert.ToDecimal(TextBoxAmt1.Text))
myinvoice.setlineitemamount2(Convert.ToDecimal(TextBoxAmt2.Text))
```

The reason is that (amount1 = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBoxAmt1.Text)) is an in-line comparison. It'll be resolving to true or false...

Also, I recommend you turn on "Option Explicit"

Answer (score 0):

You should always assign the text property of a text box to a variable and then pass the variable to a method.

Have a look at these videos

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3FEE93A664B3B2E7&feature=plcp